# Using tablelayout in Realtivelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, tablelayout

[image]

i an having trouble getting the following layout, can some one help to get the following layout..the total background should be white.Any help is appreciated

below is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/askabud" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fbedittext"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/saysomething"
        android:lines="6"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/fbcancel" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fbedittext"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/facebooks1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fbedittext"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/people" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

can someone suggest how can i get roundcorners for edit text and dropdown. thanks

Comment: Can you post your .xml file for this?

Comment: `RelativeLayout` is enough for this layout.

Comment: post your xml code here so that we can see whats going wrong...

Comment: i am not getting idea how to implement that..looking for xml file

Comment: @Abhjith how to get dropdown?

Comment: Ashreya Shah ..edited my question with xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the changes I made in your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fbedittext"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="saysomething"
        android:lines="6"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/fbedittext"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fbedittexts" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fbedittext" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You don't need LinearLayout. You can use `android:layout_marginRight` for spacing from right corner.
For dropdown, you can use [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot..yes spinner is the only choice

Answer (score 3):

For rounded corners of editext you can define a roundcorner.xml in drawables folder which says

```
<corners android:radius="14dp" />
```

And then in your xml mention this as a background for the edittext.

```
android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
```

Check this for drop down http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: Thank you Sweety..any idea how to get dropdown?

Comment: Check this for drop down http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html